# Partial touchscreen Malfunctions after wake-up

Tags: suspend, touchscreen

Sup folks.
I run Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with gnome on Wayland.
Sometimes (not every time) after waking up from sleep mode some elements don't respond to touch. (Mouse and keyboard are working fine tho.)
System things like pressing "Activities" on the top left corner do respond to touch, while other things like opening a new tab doesn't.
Another example would be - touching the screen on terminal will open the on-screen keyboard while while touching the google search bar won't.
Rebooting fixes it but I want a permanent solution.
Any ideas on how to fix it would be great. Thanks.